# ul inside an li displays underneath white area?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JQuery carousel that displays fine, however its content I want to display witha slight tweak:

```
<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; position: relative; overflow: auto;" jcarouselindex="1"><img width="331" height="155" src="images/tmp/saying1.png" alt="image description here" title="image description here"><ul class="carousel-caption"><li class="item">Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</li><li class="text">Harry Potter video lorem ipsum dolor</li></ul></li>
```

Basically I want the carousel-caption ul to display 10px to the left, however when I set the property margin-left:-10px; it displays 'underneath' a white space area?

parent li css:

```
element.style {
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    overflow: auto;
}

.jcarousel-skin-brag-small .jcarousel-item-horizontal {
    margin: 0 0 0 63px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
.jcarousel-skin-brag-small .jcarousel-item {
    height: 235px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 331px;
}

.carousel-caption {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Any ideas?  Probably me being stupid!

SEE IMAGE HERE:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1499762/sample.png

Comment: It's hard to imagine... is there any chance of you uploading an image of what you're getting and what you want?

Comment: @Pizzicato: An image with a list right next to it? Like the way users are displayed here; an icon and right next to it name and rep. It's not that hard to imagine..

Comment: Ok! At first I thought you had a CSS file and not showing its content. Anyways, when I do this kind of stuff I don't use lists... Try Divs next time, it's simpler and more flexible. Besides, lists are usually used for lists or menus... accesibility piece of advice.

Comment: can you try the carousel-caption z-index: 1; ?

Comment: Do you use firebug (firefox), or chrome and safari developers tools? It's really useful for this kind of stuff! Yo can change CSS values on the fly and get a preview right away. It has really helped me so far in this kind of horrible CSS stuff! :)

Comment: By the way, what i said before about lists is not completely true: I would use a list for a carrousel, it's a list of elements (image+caption), but what I meant is that each element shouldn't be a list... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Make the image float to the left (`float: left`).

Comment: float:left; on the img did not seem to make any difference.